# PHP Function Help: Creating a Simple Function for Repetitive Task

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I'm new to utilizing PHP fully, so I think this is just my lack of understanding the proper syntax.

I've got a home page that's being built with WordPress and Advanced Custom Fields. The images are the same thing over and over again for different data, so proper time to create a function correct?

This is my function:

```
<?php
    function homeMobImgLayout($flexibleLayout) {
        $pageID = '333';

        // check if the flexible content field has rows of data
        if( have_rows('$flexibleLayout', $pageID ) ):

         // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('$flexibleLayout', $pageID ) ) : the_row();


        // 100% Image
        if( get_row_layout() == 'image_100' ):

        $img = get_sub_field('img');
        $alt = get_sub_field('alt');

        echo '<div class="imagePod width100 clearfix">';
        echo '<img src="' . $img . '" alt="' . $alt . '" />';
        echo '</div>';


        // 50% Image
        elseif( get_row_layout() == 'image_50' ):

        $img = get_sub_field('img');
        $alt = get_sub_field('alt');

        echo '<div class="imagePod width50 clearfix">';
        echo '<img src="' . $img . '" alt="' . $alt . '" />';
        echo '</div>';

        endif;

        endwhile;

        else :
        // no layouts found
        endif;
        }
?>
```

The only thing that needs to change with each instance of the function call is the two places where I've got the variable $flexibleLayout

```
(if( have_rows('$flexibleLayout', $pageID ) ):

while ( have_rows('$flexibleLayout', $pageID ) ) : the_row();
```

So then with each instance I call the function, I though I just passed what I wanted this value to be.

Examples:

```
<?php
    homeMobImgLayout("pet_boarding_imgs");
?>
```

and

```
<?php
    homeMobImgLayout("dog_boarding_imgs");
?>
```

Where is my understanding and/or syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'$flexibleLayout'` is literally the string "$flexibleLayout".
If you want to use a variable, use a variable (without quotes):

```
if (have_rows($flexibleLayout, $pageID)) :
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @deceze. I knew it was something simple I overlooked. Appreciate it. Will accept the answer after the allotted minimum time passes.